# Different types of fevers (jwara), does anybody have the complete list of them?

Tags: scripture, health

In Hanuman vadvanal stotra we come across this:

> ॐ ह्रां ह्रीं ॐ नमो भगवते महा-वीर-वीराय सर्वदुःख निवारणाय ग्रहमण्डल
> सर्वभूतमण्डल सर्व-पिशाचमण्डलोच्चाटन भूत-ज्वर **एकाहिक-ज्वर द्वाहिक-ज्वर**
> **त्राहिक-ज्वर चातुर्थिक-ज्वर** संताप-ज्वर विषम-ज्वर ताप-ज्वर
> **माहेश्वर-वैष्णव-ज्वरान्** ‌छिन्दि-छिन्दि यक्ष ब्रह्मराक्षस
> भूत-प्रेत-पिशाचान्‌ उच्चाटय-उच्चाटय स्वाहा ।

In English:

> Om hraam hreem om namo bhagwate  mahaaviira-viiraaya sarva-dukha
> nivaaraNaaya graha-mandala sarva- Bhoot-mandala
> sarva-pisaacha-mandalochchaaTana Bhoota-jvara  **ekaahika-jvara**
> **dwayahika-jvara trayaahika-jvara** **chaaturThika-jvara**  santaapa-jvara
> vishama-jvara taapa-jvara **maaheshvara VaishNava- jvaraan** chindi-chindi
> yaksha brahma-raakshasa Bhoota-preta  pishaachaan
> uchchaataya-uchchaataya swaaha

I want to know what exactly are "ekaahika-jvara (एकाहिक-ज्वर), dwayahika-jvara (द्वाहिक-ज्वर), trayaahika-jvara, chaaturThika-jvara and maaheshvara, VaishNava- jvara ( माहेश्वर-वैष्णव-ज्वरान्‌)? and if possible their causes.
**Also does any scripture lists out all possible jvaras?**

Comment: I learnt from a book that Trayahika etc. are fevers which recur after that many days. So, Trayahika comes back after 3 days then goes away and then again repeats after 3 days.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on maaheshvara and vaishnava jvara? When I search I come across some sort of story of krishna and Shiva. https://hi.krishnakosh.org/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3/%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83._684

Comment: No, I can't remember anything about Maheswara and Vaishnava Jwaras right now. Probably I have read but forgotten.